# Удаление объекта из Map между действиями проверки и получения элемента в другом потоке

Tags: java

Допустим, имеется `ConcurrentHashMap`, с которой работает много потоков. В один момент из нее могут удалить или изменить объект. Может ли произойти, что во время проверки условия или действия объект удалится?

Для примера код:

```
if (mOrdersMap.containsKey(id) && mOrdersMap.get(id).getStatus() == WAIT) {
    mOrdersMap.get(id).handle();
}
```

Этот участок кода я разбил бы на три действия:

1. Проверка условия 1: `mOrdersMap.containsKey(id)`.
2. Проверка условия 2: `mOrdersMap.get(id).getStatus() == WAIT`.
3. Действие с объектом: `mOrdersMap.get(id).handle()`.

Есть ли вероятность того, что между первым и вторым или вторым и третьим действиями из `Map` удалят этот элемент (если именно в этот момент может поступить команда удаления)?

И насколько оправдана вот такая "проверка" в случае, если работа идет в многопоточной среде, где к `Map` обращаются в большом количестве:

```
synchronized(mOrdersMap) {
    //Действия из примера кода выше
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может. Ничего не мешает другому потоку удалить из хэш-таблицы данный ключ `id` между действиями `mOrdersMap.containsKey(id)` и `mOrdersMap.get(id).getStatus()`. В этом можно убедиться на примере:

```
private static volatile boolean isWorking = true;
private static final Map<Integer, Object> mOrdersMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final int id = 1;
    int tries = 0;
    int errorsCount = 0;
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (isWorking)
            {
                mOrdersMap.remove(id);
                mOrdersMap.put(id, this);
            }
        }
    }).start();
    while (isWorking)
    {
        if (mOrdersMap.containsKey(id))
        {
            if (mOrdersMap.get(id) == null)
            {
                errorsCount++;
            }
            tries++;
        }
        isWorking = (errorsCount < 1000 && tries < 1000 * 1000);
    }
    System.out.println("Tries: " + tries + ", Errors: " + errorsCount);
}
```

Один поток постоянно добавляет и удаляет объект в `mOrdersMap` по заданному ключу, а другой - проверяет полученное методом `get` значение в случае, если метод `containsKey` вернул `true`.

Результаты получаются вроде такого:

```
Tries: 9487, Errors: 1000
```

---

При использовании же `synchronized (mOrdersMap)`:

```
synchronized (mOrdersMap)
{
    mOrdersMap.remove(id);
    mOrdersMap.put(id, this);
}
```

и

```
synchronized (mOrdersMap)
{
    if (mOrdersMap.containsKey(id))
    {
        if (mOrdersMap.get(id) == null)
        {
            errorsCount++;
        }
        tries++;
    }
}
```

ситуация кардинально меняется:

```
Tries: 1000000, Errors: 0
```

---

`containsKey` и 2 `get`-a можно объединить в один `get`:

```
Object object = mOrdersMap.get(id);
if (object != null)
{
    tries++;
}
```

В таком случае ошибок тоже не будет. Однако, как и в первом случае, возможны ситуации, при которых действия будут производиться с объектом, которого уже нет в хэш-таблице (но он в ней был на момент вызова метода `get`).

Comment: В моей ситуации решением будет синхронизация `Map` на время удаления. В целом, система сможет это пережить. Но как этот вопрос решается в больших системах, где задержка на 100 мс не приемлема?

Comment: @RostislavDugin опыта работы с многопоточным программированием лично у меня крайне мало, так что, возможно, полноценно на этот вопрос ответит кто-то другой. Третий вариант, который я добавил в конец ответа, конкретно в этой ситуации может помочь обойтись без `synchronized` и появления `NullPointerException`. В общем же случае я бы остановился на блоке `synchronized`, если нужно обязательно работать с хэш-таблицей и выполнять атомарно несколько действий.

Comment: Я тоже не из рядов Java EE программистов, но пришлось и свой сервер писать :). Час назад совместил третий вариант с синхронизацией, главное - чтобы работало. Когда закончу, познакомлюсь с профилировщиком и, если результат будет неприемлем - начну оптимизировать. Ведь как писал один умный автор (то ли из Thinking in Java, то ли Clean Code): - "Преждевременная оптимизация - источник проблем и плохого кода".

Comment: Изменение поля isWorking в разных потоках требует использование volatile или атомарного примитива из пакета java.util.concurrent

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov в первоначальной версии кода (у меня на компе) `volatile` у `isWorking` было. А потом при переделке кода куда-то делось. Спасибо, поправил.